# How to validate an attribute from a JSON in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json, authentication

This is a project from school where I have to make a Log in app, send a json array with user and password and get a response like this:

```
{
   "respuesta": true
}
```

So, I know this seems pretty easy but I have no idea how to validate that response, this what I have in code:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  NSDictionary *jsonRecieved = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:datosWeb options:kNilOptions error:NULL];
  NSString *response = [jsonRecieved objectForKey:@"respuesta"];

if ([response  isEqual: @"true"]) {
    //do whatever I have to do here after succesfull login
}
```

Comment: You have using isEqualToString like this  [response isEqualToString:@"true"]

Answer (score 1):

You want to read the response, if I understood you correctly.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  NSDictionary *jsonRecieved = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:datosWeb options:kNilOptions error:NULL];
  NSNumber *response = [jsonRecieved objectForKey:@"respuesta"]; // the value is a number, not a string. It is not in quotation marks

  if ([response  isEqual:@YES]) // Compare to an NSNumber object with the value of YES
  { 
    …
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Looks fairly close. But, since you're checking a response for a string you will need to change your if condition slightly, and your JSON. Change your JSON to return a string value by wrapping true in quotes "true", in your if condition you will want to check if your response is equal to "true" character by character.

From:

```
{
  "respuesta": true
}

if ([response  isEqual: @"true"]) {

}
```

To:

```
{
  "respuesta": "true"
}

if ([response isEqalToString: @"true"]){

}
```

Not knowing the requirements of your project, it is hard to tell which way is better. To compare strings (not the best) or to change your condition and your data to match an NSNumber.

Comment: Even it would be possible to change the response of the server for him, one should not encode a boolean value as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this one it may help to you

```
- (void)requestFinished_list_my_product:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

SBJsonParser *json = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary* oDict = [json objectWithString:[request responseString]];


NSLog(@"Signup Response oDict  = %@",oDict);


   if ([[oDict valueForKey:@"status_code"] integerValue] == 1)
   {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:[oDict valueForKey:@"message"]  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
            alert.tag = 1;
            [alert show];



    }
    else
    {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fejl" message:[oDict valueForKey:@"msg"]  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the response value is boolean, use

```
BOOL booleanValue = [[jsonRecieved objectForKey:@"respuesta"]boolValue];
if (booleanValue) {

    }
```